# Disable Setup Button in Salesforce but also need "View Setup and Configuration Permission" in Profile for Metadata Deployement

Tags: community, permissions, profile, ui, setup

I have a lightning component that is used to create and edit Metadata using Metadata API Deployment.I have created a System admin user for this because only System Admin user has "Author Apex" Permission which is required for this .

Now I dont want the User to see Setup Button which can be done by Unchecking "View Setup and Configuration Permission" but I need that permission. So is there another way to do it.

[image]

Comment: I dont think its possible, for disabling setup the permission, you mentioned, should be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have it both ways. The View Setup and Configuration permission is required to view any metadata at all, much less update it.